# Pusher won't do jQuery events

Tags: jquery, pusher

Hey so I have this code:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $("#element").html(data);
});
```

But the jQuery html event isn't working. The alert works, but why won't the jQuery work?

Comment: What is the `data` variable - a string or JSON? Does an element exist on the page with an `id` attribute with a value of `element`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work if:

- You have loaded the jquery library
- the #element object exists in DOM.
- The data variable has non-empty string value